# Passing a javascript var in google map infowindow content?

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, anchor, infowindow

I want to pass a value in a javascript call from a google map infowindow. Since this editor will not let me paste the code directly, I am hoping you get the idea from the description.

I am setting the content of the infowindow with an html anchor that fires a javascript function, but I am unable to pass a var in the markup.

a href=javascrpit:addcoupon() to a href=javascrpit:addcoupon(aVar).

I have tried several syntax ways of doing it but can't accomplish it.

Even though the function is called, I would like to add a variable to the javascript function call but am having no luck. The value is simply named 'value'.

How could I pass that value in the addcoupon call?

Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing what's in `value`, I'm not sure how to help you.  However, you really shouldn't be concatenating arbitrary data into HTML like this, or you could run into interesting injection vulnerabilities.  At a minimum, you may be generating invalid HTML that won't always parse correctly.  Use innerText instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

In html:

```
<a onclick="addcoupon()"></a>
```

Then in your js

```
addcoupon = function() {
val = document.getElementById("value");
// do whatever with value
}
```